# How to turn a string passed through a constructor in to a variable?

Tags: c++, constructor

One of my current projects requires me to send an actual name of a file into a class but I can't figure out how to turn the string into a variable. In other words I need to turn `Andrew` in to the variable `name` in the `Person` class.

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h" 

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
Person p1("Andrew");

}
```

**Person.h**

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class Person 
 {
 public:
    Person (string name);
    void setName(string name) {string name = name;}
    void printName(string name) {cout << name;} 
private:
    string name; 
  };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, note that here you are declaring a variable local to `setName` and simply assigning it to itself:

```
void setName(string name) {string name = name;}
```

The member `name` is left unaffected. You instead want:

```
void setName(string name) { this->name = name; }
```

You can do very much the same with the constructor:

```
Person (string name) { this->name = name; }
```

However, this has a little issue. When you create a `Person` object, the `name` member will first be constructed as an empty string and then assigned to. That's completely pointless. It'd be great if we could construct it with the value given by the argument straight away. In fact, we can, with a member initialization list:

```
Person (string name)
  : name(name)
{ }
```

This basically says "initialize the `name` member with the `name` parameter".

You also have a problem with `printName`. It takes a string argument and then prints that out. It seems more likely that you'd want to print out the `name` member:

```
void printName() {cout << name;}
```

Comment: His `printName` method has a similar problem: it prints out the value passed in as a parameter, instead of printing out the member `name`, which is probably what he actually intended.

Comment: @Edward Thanks, I didn't notice that. I've added it.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the member variable:

```
Person(string n) : name(n) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of Person, do this:

```
Person (string name)
{
   this->name = name;
}
```

**or**

you can use member initialization list:

```
Person(string name)
: name(name) {}
```

**or**

you can just call your function setName in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

you need to perform `{string name = name;}` inside your constructor, not in set name.

so :

```
 class Person 
 {

 public:
    Person (string name) { this->name = name;}

    void printName(string name) {cout << name;} 
 private:
    string name; 
  };
```

and I would use different variable names like `name` and `my_name` so there are no confusions.

Comment: `string this.name = name;` is syntactic nonsense. You probably meant `this->name = name;`

Comment: Sorry, it didn't occur to me that I can edit my answer. I'm very new on here. Thanks for fixing it.